# Meteor Wonky Magic imports

Tags: meteor, import, imports-loader

I've been using meteor for a little while now, and am running into an unexpected behavior I've got my file system set up like:

```
-workspace
    -client
    -server
    -shared
        -shared.js
```

Inside of shared.js I create my mongo collections:

`Collection= new Mongo.Collection('collection');`

I can then reference them as global variable from anywhere in my app. The interesting part is: I never once use the word 'shared' in my project, meaning, I never imported this file, I never required this file, it's loading by itself, and working without ever being told to.

I'm currently trying to replicate this in another project, to no avail. Could anyone explain why it's loading in one project, and not another? And how I might get this behavior in my second project?

After looking into it, it appears that in my second project, shared.js is never loaded at all.

Comment: Meteor will load all files outside of any directory named imports/ in the application using the default file load order rules.

see docs https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#meteor-structure

Comment: So, why does it not work in my other project with the same file structure?

Answer (score 2):

*I'm guessing that your two projects were not created with the same Meteor version.*

Since **Meteor 1.7**, new projects have **lazy loading enabled by default** even outside the `imports/` folder.

This is made by the property `mainModule` inside the `package.json` file :

```
"mainModule": {
  "client": "client/main.js",
  "server": "server/main.js"
},
```

If you want to use the **eager loading** (disable the lazy loading) you have to remove the mainModule property from your `package.json`.

---

More resources here:

- *Meteor Guide to use the ES Modules:* https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#es2015-modules
- *Meteor Blog Post about 1.7:* https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-1-7-and-the-evergreen-dream-a8c1270b0901

Comment: I tried removing that bit from package.json, but it doesn't seem to have done anything

Comment: Might need to do a meteor reset to trigger a fresh build

Comment: @SpencerCornwall Check that you're not using the `export` keyword in your shared files.

Comment: Could you please add a link to a Meteor resource (docs, guide, blog or forum post) that explains the lazy loading? Just for completeness, SEO and so on :-)

Comment: @Jankapunkt i edited the answer, hope that you will find what you want.

Comment: @GaëtanRouziès I'm not using export, and I've taken out the snippet mentioned in the answer, but it's still not loading the script

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by moving it earlier in the load order (renaming the shared folder to start with an "a") But if I could have someone explain lazy loading a bit clearer to me, I'd appreciate that