# Q: SimpleSchema.extendOptions is not a function, why is this?

Tags: meteor

I'm following along with a Meteor course on Lynda, but am getting this error when trying to run my application:

```
/Users/dan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_4.h9dep8.vdm4s++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
throw(ex);
^

TypeError: SimpleSchema.extendOptions is not a function
at members.js (imports/api/members.js:4:14)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
at main.js (server/main.js:1:100)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
at /Users/dan/Desktop/hotel/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:164:15
at /Users/dan/Desktop/hotel/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
at Array.forEach ()
at /Users/dan/Desktop/hotel/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
at /Users/dan/Desktop/hotel/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
at Function.run (/Users/dan/Desktop/hotel/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
at /Users/dan/Desktop/hotel/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

As someone quite new to this, I have no idea what the problem is. My 
packages are installed correctly:

```
aldeed:collection2-core
"simpl-schema": "^1.5.3"
```

Please could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with a downgraded version? Can you also show please how you import the SimpleSchema?

Comment: If the tutorial you read has been published before Meteor 1.7, they may be using (eager loading). Since Meteor 1.7 eager loading is disabled by default, you have two choice: enabling the eager loading or using imports statements. To enable eager loading you can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51368422/4601487